# proper usage of async and await in JS?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
import Firebase from './Firebase'
import videoManager from './videoManage';

   async function getAllDatabaseLocations() {
        await let ref = Firebase.database().ref("locations")
        var user_locations = [];
        ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (datas) {
                const data = datas.val();

                vid_manage = new videoManager(data.videourl);
                vid_ref = vid_manage.getLocationVideoUrl();
                vid_ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                    videourl = url;
                   }).catch(function (error) {
                });
                let lokation = data.lokation;
                let videourl = data.videourl;
                let openinghours = data.openinghours;
                let links = data.links;

                let Lokationer = {
                    lokation: lokation,
                    videoUrl: videourl,
                    openingshours: openinghours,
                    links: links
                };

                console.log("Location objects are: ", Lokationer);
                user_locations.push(Lokationer);
                // location_obj.push(Lokationer);

            });                
        });
        return user_locations;
    }

export default getAllDatabaseLocations;
```

This method always returns an empty array, even if the console inside the loop prints as i expected? How to use async and await property so as to return an array with all Lokationer objects inside on it.

Comment: The await would go before an async function or function that returns a promise. I can't speak to whether this would be applicable to your Firebase call, but if it is you would put await to the right of the = in the assignment, just before the call that you want to wait for a result from. So `let ref = await Firebase.[...]`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return a new promise because of the asynchronous `ref.on("value")` callback.

```
function getAllDatabaseLocations() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      ...
      // when done filling the array
      resolve(user_locations);
    });
  });
}

const userLocations = await getAllDatabaseLocations(); // user_locations
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. But I can't get all object pushed into user_locations array. Only few objects get pushed into user_locations.